# android runtime linking issue with interface

Tags: android, makefile, embedded-linux, static-linking, android-build

I am trying to build an application and an interface jar using he android build system in Linux
My application has a dependency with my interface, hence I have to make interface jar ready before application make.

But we faced build/run time issues while using our newly built interface jar.
We have tried to make the application in two different sequence.

Case 1. Building the interface as local module and linking it with apk as LOCAL_JAVA_LIBRARIES.
Case 2. Building the interface as local module and linking it with apk as LOCAL_PREBUILT_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES.

### Following are the Android.mk files for main and interface.

1.Main Andriod.mk file:
**/source/Android.mk**

=======================================

STACK_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

LOCAL_PATH := $(STACK_PATH)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

include $(LOCAL_PATH)/interface/Android.mk

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_PATH := $(STACK_PATH)

include $(LOCAL_PATH)/application/Android.mk

=======================================

2.Interface Android.mk :
**/source/interface/Android.mk**

=======================================

LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-subdir-java-files, src)

LOCAL_MODULE := MyInterface

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional

LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := JAVA_LIBRARIES

LOCAL_JAVA_RESOURCE_DIRS := src

include $(BUILD_JAVA_LIBRARY)

$(call dist-for-goals, droidcore, $(full_classes_jar):MyInterface.jar)

=======================================

### Following are the Android.mk files for application in CASE 1.

Application Android.mk:
**/source/application/Android.mk**

=======================================

TOP_LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

LOCAL_PATH:= $(TOP_LOCAL_PATH)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-subdir-java-files)

LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := MyApplication

LOCAL_JAVA_LIBRARIES := MyInterface

include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)

include $(BUILD_MULTI_PREBUILT)

=======================================

Build completed successfully .But when trying to run this application, it shows this error.
I/dalvikvm( XXXX): Failed resolving Lcom/test/example/application; interface XXX 'Lcom/test/example/interface;'
W/dalvikvm( XXXX): Link of class 'Lcom/test/example/application;' failed

### Following are the Android.mk files for application in CASE 2.

Application Android.mk
**/source/application/Android.mk**

=======================================

TOP_LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

LOCAL_PATH:= $(TOP_LOCAL_PATH)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

$(shell (cp $(LOCAL_PATH)/../out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/Interface_intermediates/classes-jarjar.jar $(LOCAL_PATH)/applications/libs/MyInterface.jar ))

LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES += MyInterface

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-subdir-java-files)

LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := MyApplicationss

LOCAL_PREBUILT_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES += MyInterface:libs/MyInterface.jar

include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)

include $(BUILD_MULTI_PREBUILT)

=======================================

This resulted in a build error as follows.

**build/core/base_rules.mk:166: * source/applications: MODULE.TARGET.JAVA_LIBRARIES.MyInterface already defined by source/interface.  Stop.**

But when they are built seperately without using the build system, this problem is not there.Also the application runs without error.

---

When the interface was built to Myinterface.jar using the eclipse, and build the application-apk using this
interface jar(by linking statically) in Linux, the application ran smoothly.

Is there any issue in our Android.mk files? Please review and give your suggestions